# Run pip from Ubuntu terminal on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, terminal

When I run this command in the Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10:

```
victor@DUMMYPC:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/programming$ pip show numpy
```

I receive this message:

```
Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pip
```

On the other hand, when I run whereis:

```
victor@DUMMYPC:/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/programming$ whereis pip
```

The system seems to find it:

```
pip: /mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Continuum/miniconda3/Scripts/pip.exe
```

I wonder what I would have to do to fix things and have execute pip without issues from the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Perhaps try `pip.exe show numpy`.

Comment: Hey. It works. You can post the answer so I can Accept it. Thanks @Anaksunaman

Comment: And you're welcome. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [official WSL documentation from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop):

> WSL can invoke Windows binaries directly from the WSL command line using `[binary name].exe`. For example, `notepad.exe`.

Therefore, running `pip.exe show numpy` is the correct way to call `pip` in this instance (since `pip` was installed under Windows).